# Blazemeter crashes with jmx files

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

[image]

I've been trying to upload my jmx test scripts to Blazemeter but it always gives me this screen after running the test. Any common mistakes I could be making that would lead to this issue? Here are some of the log reports too, they don't make much sense to me. There appears to be some problem with a yaml file but I didn't upload one, so if it needs one to work that might be it. Any help or advice is appreciated, thanks.

```
[13-08-21 02:14:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to PREPARING_PROVISIONING (14)
    [13-08-21 02:14:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to CONFIGURING_DEPENDENCIES (10)
    [13-08-21 02:14:51] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to PREPARING_PROVISIONING (14)
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: Verify file path /usr/local/taurus-cloud/files
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: file path created
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: Verify file path /tmp/artifacts/admin
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: [Init Info: Before init variables]                     
                                original_config: https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/original-config                     
                                custom_config: https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/custom-config                     
                                EVENTS_URL: https://data.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/events                     
                                FILE_NAME: TestPlan _1_.jmx                     
                                SCRIPT_TYPE: jmeter                     
                                INSTANCE ID: None
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: file path created
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: Verify file path /tmp/artifacts
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: file path created
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: Verify file path /usr/local
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: Verify file path /usr/local/bztcloud
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: file path created
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Session id is set
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: file path created
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Starting Taurus Cloud - Cloud Launcher
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Testing Operation System: ***linux***
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Running Taurus update
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Starting Taurus update
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Taurus update complete
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: [Init Info: After init variables]                     
                                original_config: https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/original-config                     
                                custom_config: https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/custom-config                     
                                EVENTS_URL: https://data.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/events                     
                                FILE_NAME: TestPlan _1_.jmx                     
                                SCRIPT_TYPE: jmeter                     
                                INSTANCE ID: None
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Running blacklist check
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Applying blacklist
    [13-08-21 02:15:48] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Prepare: Preparing test launcher environment
    [13-08-21 02:15:49] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Getting base configuration from configuration file https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/original-config and additional configuration from the custom configuration https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/custom-config
    [13-08-21 02:15:49] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Blacklist check completed (Check: 1)
    [13-08-21 02:15:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Downloading the configuration file from https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/original-config
    [13-08-21 02:15:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Running BZT...
    [13-08-21 02:15:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: verify_ssl value: 
    [13-08-21 02:15:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to INIT_SCRIPT (50)
    [13-08-21 02:15:50] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Downloading the custom configuration file from https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/taurus/r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493/custom-config
    [13-08-21 02:15:50] [WARNING]   [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Error handling original config as yaml; saving file as is
    [13-08-21 02:15:53] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Running command: atop ('-a', '-w', '/tmp/artifacts/admin/atop.binlog', '15')
    [13-08-21 02:15:54] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Jetlag: Download process completed
    [13-08-21 02:15:54] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Jetlag: Skip download ()
    [13-08-21 02:15:55] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Jetpack: Download process completed
    [13-08-21 02:15:55] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Jetpack: Downloading skipped (No URL)
    [13-08-21 02:16:00] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Jetpack: Starting jetpack...
    [13-08-21 02:16:00] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Jetpack: Version 5.0.1
    [13-08-21 02:16:19] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to TAURUS_ENGINE_READY (90)
    [13-08-21 02:16:19] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to TAURUS_ENGINE_INIT (71)
    [13-08-21 02:36:26] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to TERMINATING (130)
    [13-08-21 02:36:41] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to TAURUS_BZT_DONE (135)
    [13-08-21 02:36:42] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Collecting atop.binlog - saving to log file
    [13-08-21 02:36:42] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Starting cloud shutdown
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/jetpack.properties
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving admin artifacts and creating zip
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/merged.yml
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/merged.json
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/final-overrides.yml
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/jetlag-download.log
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/effective.json
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/network_checking.log
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [WARNING]   [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: File /tmp/artifacts/taurus-base-config.yml not found on disk
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/jetpack.log
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/cloud-launcher.log
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/taurus-custom-config.yml
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/exported.jetlag.ldjson
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/effective.yml
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/jetpack-download.log
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [WARNING]   [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: File /tmp/artifacts/taurus_start.log not found on disk
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Moving file /tmp/artifacts/jetlag.log
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Zipping artifacts into file /tmp/artifacts/admin-artifacts.zip
    [13-08-21 02:36:43] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Zipping path /tmp/artifacts/admin
    [13-08-21 02:36:44] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Admin artifacts zip files generated [/tmp/artifacts/admin-artifacts.zip, /tmp/artifacts/admin-artifacts.zip.tail.bz]
    [13-08-21 02:36:44] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Zipping artifacts into file /tmp/artifacts/artifacts.zip
    [13-08-21 02:36:44] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Zipping path /tmp/artifacts
    [13-08-21 02:37:25] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Artifacts zip files generated [/tmp/artifacts/artifacts.zip, /tmp/artifacts/artifacts.zip.tail.bz]
    [13-08-21 02:37:28] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to TAURUS_IMAGE_DONE (136)
    [13-08-21 02:37:28] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Taurus completed (Exit: 1)
    [13-08-21 02:37:28] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: 0 seconds until process run completion
    [13-08-21 02:37:28] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Finished file upload
    [13-08-21 02:37:29] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Status changed to ENDED (140)
    [13-08-21 02:37:29] [INFO]  [r-v4-6116b69a143f3372092493]   system: Terminate command sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this form of questions should go to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

I can only guess that BlazeMeter engine might not like your  `TestPlan _1_.jmx` filename, try removing spaces and underscores, it might fix the problem.

Also you can look at the [BZT.log file](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303897-Logs-Report-Logs-Report#h_10c4b073-a85c-4a9f-9a2d-4175929a0e15) from the [Logs Report](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303897-Logs-Report-Logs-Report) view, most probably it will be way more informative.